# How to check if a thread from a previous session is still running when I reopen the application?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My application is starting a continously running thread which runs a while(true){}. When I reopen/reenter the application another thread is created and works concurrently with the previous. I would like a mechanism which could check whether a thread from a previous session is still running and if it does then it shouldn't recreate it. How to achieve that?

Comment: @JohnVint yes they should. Since the application is running on an android device. Ignore the case when the phone is shut down because then those threads are killed anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your thread create a

```
Boolean isRunning = false;
```

When your thread starts 
put it in the apps shared preference like this..

```
  isRunning = true;
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("isThreadRunning", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("isRunning", isRunning);
  editor.commit();
```

Now when the thread is Finished just change it back to false.

```
isRunning = false;
```

In your activity just pull the boolean out of shared preference like this.

```
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("isThreadRunning", 0);
   boolean running = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false); //if it doesnt exist it will automatically set to false which means the thread hasnt or isnt running

 then just test.

 if(running){
 //Do something
 }else{
 //the thread isnt running so lets start it.
 }
```

This is a very easy way to do it.

Hope it helps

Comment: After the thread finishes and is set back to false make sure you place it in the bundle as i did in the first line of code.

Comment: thanks this seems as a very nice and simple solution, is SharedPreferences persisted when shut down occurs? Because if it does then my isRunning will be always set to true, even though the thread was killed by the shut down.

Comment: Yes SharedPreference is persistent! Thats whats awesome about it. It actually writes to a xml file.

Answer (score 1):

One way: Create a preference file with a simple boolean to say running or not.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about it but wanted to see other peoples suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple thread listing a while back. user1031312 has a better solution, but here it is anyways in case it's useful to you. Not sure if it will list threads from a previous session though. It will list the thread names and id's in a TextView called thread_textview.

```
// This method recursively visits all thread groups under 'group'.
public static void visit(ThreadGroup group, int level) {
    // Get threads in 'group'
    int numThreads = group.activeCount();
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[numThreads*2];
    numThreads = group.enumerate(threads, false);

    // Enumerate each thread in 'group'
    for (int i=0; i<numThreads; i++) {
        // Get thread
        thread_textview.append("-> "+threads[i].getName()+":"+threads[i].getId()+"\n");
    }

    // Get thread subgroups of 'group'
    int numGroups = group.activeGroupCount();
    ThreadGroup[] groups = new ThreadGroup[numGroups*2];
    numGroups = group.enumerate(groups, false);

    // Recursively visit each subgroup
    for (int i=0; i<numGroups; i++) {
        visit(groups[i], level+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ServerSocket to bind to a port. At one time the OS will only allow one thread to be bound. This will prevent the next one to not execute.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
```

For next thread it will throw BindException. So first line in your thread and it will do what you want.

p.s. 1234 is an unused port number.

Another option -- the above answer is probably not suitable to what you want so here is another option.

```
public MyThreadFactory {

     List<String> runningThreads = new List<String>();

     public synchronized void startThread(MyThread thread) {
          if (! runningThreads.contains(thread.getID())) {
                runningThreads.add(thread.getID());
                // MyThread implements Runnable
                new Thread(thread).start();
          }
     }
}
```

assuming your thread object has getID method or something that uniquely identifies its type.

Comment: although you are correct I was looking for a more generic answer, you see I have 4 while(true) threads and only 2 of them are servers, thanks anyways :)

Comment: @Mike I think I misunderstood. Are all your threads in the same process?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mention anything about the other threads, basically forget the server part, editted my question to reflect my problem more precisely. The threads are started by the main activity in onCreate().

Comment: ok that would work, but I'll have to persist MyThreadFactory and there is a problem as with the previous answers, if the device shuts down and restarts for some reason my thread will be killed but this wont be reflected in MyThreadFactory which will be still containing the Thread indicating that it is running when it actually isn't.